# Extract Information From File Name in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Suppose I have a file with a name ABC_DE_FGHI_10_JK_LMN.csv. I want to extract the ID from the file-name i.e. 10 with the help of ID position and file-name separator. I have following two inputs

```
File-name_ID_Position=4; [since 10 is at fourth position in file-name]
File-name_Delimiter="_";
```

Here ID can be numeric or alpha-numeric. So how extract the 10 from above file with the help of above two inputs. How to achieve this in bash?

Comment: Only Bash or is awk usable?

Comment: It will be OK for me if it returns the desired output and compatible to use in shell script.

Comment: `x="ABC_DE_FGHI_10_JK_LMN.csv"; x=${x#*_*_*_}; echo ${x%_*_*}`

Comment: @Cyrus, PRATIK PATIL changed the file naming convention, and why I deleted my answer, so `x="ABC_DE_FGHI_10.csv"; x=${x#*_*_*_}; echo ${x%_*_*}` returns `10.csv` not just `10` which he wants.  However with this marked as a duplicate I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Using `_` or `.` as separator: `x="ABC_DE_FGHI_10.csv"; x=${x#*[_.]*[_.]*[_.]}; echo ${x%[_.]*}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a regex in bash, I would do it with awk:

```
echo 'ABC_DE_FGHI_10_JK_LMN.csv' | awk -F_ -v pos=4 '{print $pos}'
```

or if you want the dot to also be a delimiter (requires GNU awk):

```
echo 'ABC_DE_FGHI_10_JK_LMN.csv' | awk -F'[_.]' -v pos=4 '{print $pos}'
```

Comment: What if ID comes at last position in file-name? Ex. echo 'ABC_DE_FGHI_10.csv' | awk -F_ -v pos=4 '{print $pos}' then here it returns 10.csv instead of 10

Comment: @PRATIKPATIL Then add it to the delimiter (See edit).